# $ in SUMIF function not understood

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have an Excel workbook that was upgraded from Excel 2003 to Excel 2010. One of the worksheet called `Calc_Sheet` has columns named A,B,C,D and a column called `Calc` that has the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B)
```

The above formula is for the cell in row two of the `Calc` column. Likewise, for cell in row 3 of the same column the formula displays as:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,$A3,$B:$B)
```

...and so on.

Our workbook has some worksheets that also have the names as A,B,C. I don't know if the above formula has anything to do with the worksheets A and B or it is referencing the columns A, B of the worksheet `Calc_Sheet`.

I know what a `SUMIF` function is as explained by Microsoft [here with examples](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx).

But all the examples there are using no `$` sign. So, what the above formula translate to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way your formula is written just means that if you drag that formula to the left or the right, it will still look at columns A and B, If you remove the $ then when you drag the formula to the left or the right the entire formula will change what columns it is looking at. The $ represent Absolute References, in other works whatever following the $ will not change no matter where you place the formula.

The `$` will also lock in the rows if seen before the Row number also.

```
A1 = Row and Column Will change when the formula is dragged around
$A1 = The Row number will change but not the Column  reference
A$1 = the column may change but the row will not
$A$1 = The Formula will always reference `A1` even when filled down or across.
```

***NOTE:*** Even with Absolute Referencing on, excel will modify the formula when columns are either inserted or deleted.

For an example see [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/get-to-know-excel-enter-formulas-RZ006107930.aspx?section=13)

Or

For more information please see [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/relative.aspx) Or [Here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/r/g/absolute_cell_r.htm)

***The SumIf Function***

the sytax of the *SumIf* Function is:

```
SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range)
```

Following this, syntax, You are creating a a Logical Statement (True or False) where the cells in the range specified, are compared to the criteria you provide.

If no operator is supplied but only a Number or Text value then the cells in the range provided will have to equal the criteria.

You can also use operators like the `<` and the `>` symbols.

Once you have the Range you want to test and the criteria by which you would like it tested the last part of the function is the **sum_range** here you give the formula a range of cells that it can actually sum.

The function will sum the cells in the **sum_range** where the cells in the **range** from the first p[art of the syntax meet the criteria.

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B)
```

So given your sample above. It is giving the sum of all the Number in `B:B` where the cell in `A:A` on the same row is equal to the value in `A2`.

Comment: user2140261, but in `=SUMIF($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B)` please notice that `$A:$A` and `$B:$B` are not followed by any numbers so what does that mean? In your example you are using A followed by a number 1.

Comment: When you use A:A or $A:$A that's a reference to the whole column A

Comment: The explanation from user2140261 makes sense. But the formula `=SUMIF($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B)` in the Excel workbook that was developed by someone about 10 years ago is still unclear to me since the column A in the worksheet has text values (not the numbers).

Comment: @nam I have updated my answer I hope it makes it slightly clearer for you.