# Add number count to following row?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a formula for

```
$D2 = $A1+$B2*($C1+$D1)
```

and

```
$D3 = $A2+$B2*($C2+$D2).
```

How do I make

```
$D4 = $A3+$B2*($C3+$D3)
```

and so on?

Answer (score 1):

In D2 Make it

```
 =$A1+$B$2*($C1+$D1)
```

and then drag it down. The `$` in front of the `2` in `$B$2` tells excel to never change that reference from `B2`

This is called Absolute referenceing you can learn more [From This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195280/in-sumif-function-not-understood/21195475#21195475)